# I have a array program where in the condition is have to return a new array which replace the next highest element from the array

Tags: java, arrays

lets say I have an input of [10,8,6,15,2,-1]

the output should be [15,10,8,15,6,2]

I have written a set of code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] unsortesArray=new int[]{10,8,6,15,2,-1};
        int len=unsortesArray.length;

        for(int i=0;i<len; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<len; j++){
                if(unsortesArray[i]<unsortesArray[j]){
                    unsortesArray[i]=unsortesArray[j];
                }
            }
            System.out.println(unsortesArray[i]);
        }
    }
```

but not getting the expected output. Please suggest the solution.

Comment: Can you please add the logic on the desired ouput?

Answer (score 1):

You need to swap the two numbers:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] unsortesArray=new int[]{10,8,6,15,2,-1};
    int len=unsortesArray.length;

    for(int i=0;i<len; i++){
        for(int j=i+1; j<len; j++){
            if(unsortesArray[i]<unsortesArray[j]){
                int temp = unsortesArray[i]; // create a temp var to store the value you are going to swap 
                unsortesArray[i]=unsortesArray[j]; // swap the value
                unsortesArray[j] = temp; // save it back again in the array 
            }
        }
        System.out.println(unsortesArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The o/p I expect is not from the right sun array highest element, it's just highest from ith element through out the array.

Comment: hey @RahulAnand you question is not clear, could you please elaborate.

Comment: yup the problem statement is lt's say we have an array of [10,8,6,15,2,-1] now I wanted another array as an output which will have just highest number in place of the element from the array. let's say from the input the o/p should be [15,10,8,15,6,2] as the highest of 10 is 15, of 8 is 10 not 15, of 6 is 8 not 10 or 15.